# Find missing information between 2 lists

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How can i find missing information between 2 different lists in

The code that generates the lists

```
 private static IEnumerable<User> GetSomeUsers()
        {
            var mikesGroups = new List<string> { "Group1", "Group2" };
            var mike = new User { UserName = "Mike", MemberOf = mikesGroups };

            var davidsGroups = new List<string> { "Group3", "Group1" };
            var david = new User { UserName = "David", MemberOf = davidsGroups };

            return new List<User> { mike, david };
        }


        private static IEnumerable<Group> getGroups()
        {
            var group1Users = new List<string> { "Mike", "David", "Kim" };
            var group1 = new Group { Name = "Group1", Members = group1Users };

            var group2Users = new List<string> { "Mike", "David","Kim" };
            var group2 = new Group { Name = "Group2", Members = group2Users };

            return new List<Group> { group1, group2 };
        }
```

entities:

```
public class User
    {
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public IList<string> MemberOf { get; set; } // list of group names
    }

public class Group
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<string> Members { get; set; } // list of username
}
```

Result should be 2 lists (Missing Groups and missing users)

> `Group3` is missing in the group list and linked to user `"David"`
>   `Kim` is missing in the user list and linked to `group1` and `group2`
>
> 2 dictionaries must be returned Key = missing value = foundIn

```
Dictionary<string,IList<string>> missingUsers;
Item 1 > key="Kim", Value={"Group1","Group2"}

Dictionary<string,IList<string>> missingGroup;
item 1 > Key="Group3",{"David"}
```

Edit=>

I manged to get list of all missing but not linked (list of all values in the Dictionary)

```
var missingGroups = users.SelectMany(g => g.MemberOf).ToList().Except(groups.Select(w => w.Name));
var missingUsers= groups.SelectMany(g => g.Members).ToList().Except(users.Select(u => u.UserName));
```

Comment: That's the problem, i'm blocked in the logic part

Comment: so far the following but it doesn't work

`users.Select(x => x.MemberOf).Except<string>(groups.Select(g => g.Name));´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. please feel free to correct if you found better one that has better performance.

```
        var missingGroup =
        users.ToDictionary(user => user.UserName, user => 
            user.MemberOf.Except(groups.Select(w => w.Name)))
            .Where(f => f.Value != null && f.Value.Count() > 0)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```